# Squid - the request or reply is too large

Tags: squid

I am trying to download spring framework and i face the error that is displayed below. Anyone know how to solve this?

```
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-4.2.1.RELEASE-dist.zip

The request or reply is too large.

If you are making a POST or PUT request, then the item you are trying to upload is too large.

If you are making a GET request, then the item you are trying to download is too large.

These limits have been established by the Internet Service Provider who operates this cache. Please contact them directly if you feel this is an error.
```

Comment: What are trying to do?  Is there programming code you have written that you can include in your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, Check the maximum file upload/download size configured for you parent proxy server.